# JDK 11 windows installation Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'

Tags: java, jdk

After installation of **JDK 11** and setting of the path in environment variable

In a command prompt > `java -version` returns:

```
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long day, I have found a solution. it may work for others also.

I have deleted all `.exe` file from the given below path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

After that, it worked for me.